# Missing files after apache

Tags: debian, apache-httpd

Hi I installed apache for a firefox theme and I think I messed up something?

```
sudo mv /home/myuser/FirefoxMonolite/startup-page/index.html * /var/www/html
```

then:

```
sudo systemctl enable apache2
```

and then all my files disappeared? like my documents folder and everything? My distro is Debian 12 bookworm

Comment: Why did you include the glob `*` in your command? It moved all the files in what was the current working directory.

Comment: to be honest with you i was really trying to follow a tutorial so I dont even know what it meant, i just noticed i made a typo :c

Comment: What kind of tutorial requires installing `apache` for a theme? `apache` is a web server not something related to Firefox, let alone themes.

Comment: FWIW [the command you mistyped](https://github.com/noriaku/FirefoxMonolite) should have been `sudo mv /path/to/startup-page/* /var/www/html`. But why you'd be instructed to install Apache for a Firefox theme... weird

Answer (score 2):

The `mv` command you ran acted on `*`, apparently in your home directory; it moved all your files to `/var/www/html`. Take a look at that:

```
ls -l /var/www/html
```

That should show you all your files, and you can move them back:

```
sudo mv /var/www/html/Documents ~/
```

etc.

If you want to move everything in `/var/www/html` back, run

```
sudo mv /var/www/html/* ~/
```

Comment: HI, tysm Stephen you are really kind :) i asked the same on reddit and they were so mean ;-; yeah i actually figured i wrote it wrong, luckily they were there. so I have to type the command with the ~  with every folder? sorry for all the questions and ty for taking the time to answer

Comment: You can move everything back with `sudo mv /var/www/html/* ~/` but that will also move anything that was originally in `/var/www/html`. I suggested moving a single directory/file at a time because that’s the safer option.

Comment: TYSM i got everything back, the folder didn't have anything inside! ill try to make a backup to avoid messing up T-T you're a life saver fr! ty so so much for helping me out

Comment: The backup is a very good idea, but the real life saver is not running random commands from websites that you do not understand.